# Can a if-else_if-else ladder can be written in other way in java?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to modify the format of the code lines since they don't seem nice and I want to reduce the amount of lines.

Please tell how to shorten or write in other format of the below code

```
        if (token[0][0] == token[0][1] && token[0][1] == token[0][2] && token[0][2] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[1][0] == token[1][1] && token[1][1] == token[1][2] && token[1][2] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[2][0] == token[2][1] && token[2][1] == token[2][2] && token[2][2] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[0][0] == token[1][0] && token[1][0] == token[2][0] && token[2][0] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[0][1] == token[1][1] && token[1][1] == token[2][1] && token[2][1] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[0][2] == token[1][2] && token[1][2] == token[2][2] && token[2][2] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[0][0] == token[1][1] && token[1][1] == token[2][2] && token[2][2] == 0)
            return true;
        else if (token[0][2] == token[1][1] && token[1][1] == token[2][0] && token[2][0] == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
```

It would be better if it would be like the below\

```
        if (board[0] == getUserRole) {
            if (board[1] == getUserRole)
                if (board[2] == getUserRole)
                    return true;
            if (board[3] == getUserRole)
                if (board[6] == getUserRole)
                    return true;
            if (board[4] == getUserRole)
                if (board[8] == getUserRole)
                    return true;
        }
```

It would be better if it can be written in one line mode, please try to code it within 5 lines (if possible.)
P.S.-> Only diagonals or the straights like in tic tac toe.

Comment: Looks like nested for loops that traverse the entire 2D array and dynamically do these comparisons could be useful.

Comment: In each case, you're returning if the condition is truthful.  So the else serves no purpose.

Comment: If `N` is very large, then you could implement this with recursion. But it's fine as it is if N=3.

Comment: This is a Tic-Tac-Toe problem. Is it a homework assignment?

You can solve this problem with [14 bytes of Jelly code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/144116/tic-tac-toe-x-or-o).

But I think it would be more readable to write three helper methods: isColumn, isRow, and is Diagonal.  Each one could use a loop. More code, but easier to read and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the values have to be zero for the test to be true, just add them together...

```
for(let i=0;i<=2;i++){
    if (token[i][0] + token[i][1] + token[i][2]==0 || token[0][i] + token[1][i] + token[2][i]==0)
        return true; }
return (token[0][0] + token[1][1] + token[2][2]==0 || token[0][2] + token[1][1] + token[2][0]==0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have following check pattern:

```
000 ... ... 0.. .0. ..0 0.. ..0 
... 000 ... 0.. .0. ..0 .0. .0. 
... ... 000 0.. .0. ..0 ..0 0..
```

So, all you can do is to simplify your code removed duplication.

```java
public static boolean check(int[][] token) {
    return token[0][0] == 0 && token[0][1] == 0 && token[0][2] == 0
            || token[1][0] == 0 && token[1][1] == 0 && token[1][2] == 0
            || token[2][0] == 0 && token[2][1] == 0 && token[2][2] == 0
            || token[0][0] == 0 && token[1][0] == 0 && token[2][0] == 0
            || token[0][1] == 0 && token[1][1] == 0 && token[2][1] == 0
            || token[0][2] == 0 && token[1][2] == 0 && token[2][2] == 0
            || token[0][0] == 0 && token[1][1] == 0 && token[2][2] == 0
            || token[0][2] == 0 && token[1][1] == 0 && token[2][0] == 0;
}
```

Or, probably, make it a bit cleare with functionals:

```java
public static boolean check(int[][] token) {
    IntPredicate rowZero = row -> token[row][0] == 0 && token[row][1] == 0 && token[row][2] == 0;
    IntPredicate colZero = col -> token[0][col] == 0 && token[1][col] == 0 && token[2][col] == 0;
    IntPredicate diagonalZero = i -> i == 0 ? token[0][0] == 0 && token[1][1] == 0 && token[2][2] == 0
                                            : token[0][2] == 0 && token[1][1] == 0 && token[2][0] == 0;

    return rowZero.test(0) || rowZero.test(1) || rowZero.test(2) ||
            colZero.test(0) || colZero.test(1) || colZero.test(2) ||
            diagonalZero.test(0) || diagonalZero.test(1);
}
```

Comment: The solution with || is defenetly the simplest and what I also would post as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for zeroes you could have a `boolean` array initialized to all `false`.  Then you could do something like the following.

```
if (token[0][0] && token[0][1] && token[0][2]) 
            return true;
if (token[1][0] && token[1][1] && token[1][2])
            return true;
if (token[2][0] && token[2][1] && token[2][2])
            return true;
// ...
// rest of similar conditions here
// ...

return false;
```

Of course, that depends on the overall design of your game.

Comment: Looks like this is a `int[][]`

Comment: Yes, I know.  It was a suggestion (see my first sentence).